# Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error

Tags: url, magento, url-rewriting

I was trying to remove index.php from the URL of a Magento website:
_Turn on “use webserver rewrite”
_ Set permission 755 to necessary files and folders
_ make sure mode rewrite is on
_ configure htaccess file. comment, uncomment allow symlinks, change rewrite base from /magento/ to / or /var/www/hosts/www.domainname.com/ or /hosts/www.domainname.com/ or /www.domainname.com/
_reindex, flush cache

But all results in 500 server internal error.
In the log file I can see:

```
[Fri Apr 20 11:11:59 2012] [error] [client 88.87.40.140] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/hosts/www.nordocks.no/app/etc/local.xml
[Fri Apr 20 11:12:07 2012] [error] [client 117.5.178.168] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.
```

And this is my .htaccess

```
############################################
## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

#    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
#    AddHandler php5-cgi .php

############################################
## GoDaddy specific options

#   Options -MultiViews

## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

############################################
## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting

    #AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
    #AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

############################################
## default index file

    DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>

############################################
## adjust memory limit

#    php_value memory_limit 64M
    php_value memory_limit 256M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000

############################################
## disable magic quotes for php request vars

    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

    php_flag session.auto_start off

############################################
## enable resulting html compression

    #php_flag zlib.output_compression on

###########################################
# disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

###########################################
# turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects

    php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
###########################################
# disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

    # Insert filter on all content
    ###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Insert filter on selected content types only
    #AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    #BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # Don't compress images
    #SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    #Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

############################################
## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

    SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    #RewriteBase /

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>


############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

    AddDefaultCharset Off
    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>

############################################
## By default allow all access

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

###########################################
## Deny access to release notes to prevent disclosure of the installed Magento version

    <Files RELEASE_NOTES.txt>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>

############################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

    #FileETag none
```

Please give me an instruction on how to deal with this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Set permission 755 to necessary files and folders

You've hit a rock on this one. The permissions have been changed on items that need other permissions than 755 set.

[Resetting File Permissions](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html#privs-after)

The base things to watch out for are the files & directories that must be writeable:

```
- file: magento/var/.htaccess
- directory: magento/app/etc
- directory: magento/var
- all the directories under: magento/media 

chmod o+w var var/.htaccess app/etc
chmod -R o+w media
```

Answer (score 6):

On my side it was not a permission problem but simply (and the same is in your `.htaccess`) the line with:

```
RewriteBase /
```

was commented.
Uncommenting it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.

The directory for my Magento website on my Ubuntu server is: /var/www/magento

When running Magento initial installation I selected "No" for Use Web Server Rewrites. This setting is under Admin Panel - System - General - Web.

In .htaccess of root magento folder after finishing the initial installation it had:
RewriteBase /magento/
As noted before my folder was /var/www/magento/

I changed Web Server Rewrites to Yes. In .htaccess I changed:
RewriteBase /

Works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue aswell

adding

```
RewriteBase /
```

to the .htaccess brought me a step further.
After this I ran into the next issue:

```
Could not determine temp directory, please specify a cache_dir manually";i:1;s:4307:"#0 /XXX/XXX/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend.php(217): Zend_Cache::throwException('Could not deter...')
```

Solution for this was to edit the

```
\lib\Zend\Cache\Backend\File.php
```

In the file.php search for

```
'cache_dir' => null,
```

and replace with

```
'cache_dir' => "var/tmp/",
```

I hope this saves somebody else some time.